# binding livechart to static data in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to import a csv file in my wpf application ad display the values of the column `Z` on a livechart graph.

I create the graph element in XAML

```
            <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="chart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" LegendLocation="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:LineSeries Title="Data Series" Values="{Binding SeriesCollection}" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

this is a function that imports the csv data and display the data in a listview item.

```
private async void btnLoadXyz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Setup the OpenFileDialog.
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        try
        {
            //CsvDataList = new ObservableCollection<CsvData>(); // Initialize CsvDataList

            int currentLine = 0;

            foreach (var fileName in openFileDialog.SafeFileNames)
            {
                // Collect the name of the file in a variable
                string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog.FileName), fileName);
                // Load data from the file and add it to CsvDataList
                //LoadCsvFile(filePath);
                await Task.Run(() => LoadCsvFile(filePath, ref currentLine));

            }

            lstFileText.ItemsSource = CsvDataList;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

the loadCsv function add data to an instance of this class

```
public class CsvData
{
    public float X { get; set; }
    public float Y { get; set; }
    public float Z { get; set; }
}
```

now I want to plot the `Z` values of my collection to my chart.
with a little of chatgpt help I tried:

```
List<double> values = new List<double>();
foreach (var csvData in CsvDataList)
{
    values.Add(csvData.Z);
}
foreach (var value in values)
{
    SeriesCollection[0].Values.Add(value);
}
OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SeriesCollection"));
```

this is a very slow approach because of all these for loops, and as I can see is intended to be used for a live chart update while my data is static since it`s previously imported in the collection.
also the chart does not display the data even if the code runs without errors.

in Python I am used to work with pandas dataframe I wonder if it would be more efficient to use a windows DataFrame Class to import the csv